# showInAppNotification - notification does not dismiss on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using the library `react-native-navigation` on my app, but whenever I try to add notifications  using the [`showInAppNotification`](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=showinappnotificationparams-) method, the notification is not dismissed on swipe as expected.
The notifications can be dismissed with a swipe normally on iOS. Has anyone ever had this problem?

#### Steps to Reproduce

1 - Add a notification using the `showInAppNotification` method:

```
this.props.navigator.showInAppNotification({
    screen: "example.InAppNotification",
    passProps: { ...notificationProps },
    autoDismissTimerSec: 5,
  });
```

2 - Run the application on an Android device;
3 - Trigger the notification display;
4 - Try to swipe to notification up to dismiss

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.433
- React Native version: 0.55.4
- Platform: Android
- Device info: SM-G950F - 8.0.0 - Debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Got the swipe dismiss on Android working using the `react-native-swipe-gestures` library and and `LayoutAnimation`.
Here's the general idea of the workaround, in case anyone stumbles here with the same problem:

```
class MyNotification extends React.PureComponent {

   state = {
      isNotificationDismissed: false,
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <GestureRecognizer
          style={this.getDisplayStyle()}
          onSwipeUp={this.handleSwipeUp}>
          {this.renderNotificationContent()}
        </GestureRecognizer>
      );
    }

    getDisplayStyle = () => {
      if (this.state.isNotificationDismissed) return styles.hiddenNotification;
      return styles.visibleNotification;
    };

    handleSwipeUp = () => {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
      this.setState({ isNotificationDismissed: true });
    };

   . 
   .
   .
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    visibleNotification: {
      height: 64,
    },
    hiddenNotification: {
      height: 0,
    },
});
```